# Model validation of quasi-Poisson

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, aic, quasi-likelihood

I have been running a set of quasi-Poisson generalized linear models. As there is no AIC computed with quasi-distributions I was wondering how I could compare my models. It seems that I can use QAIC but I am really confused by all the reading I have done. Is there a simple function that I can use for that?

Comment: The R package `AICcmodavg` has a QAIC function & references Burnham & Anderson (2002), *Model Selection & Multi-Model Inference*.